# process termination

Tags: process, network-programming, udp

I have 2 processes and they send UDP messeges. They don't read the messages immeditely and sometimes when they read the messages they can read a bulk of them. 
I saw that when one of the processes is down the other one is still getting those messages.

How come ? it is down.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep getting packets after one process crashes because the OS buffers the incoming packets.  See for example this discussion on [UDP Buffering](http://www.29west.com/docs/THPM/udp-buffering-background.html).

When working with unconnected UDP sockets there is no way for either pier to know if the other pier has crashed other than sending round trip keep alive packets.

Comment: OK.

If it was TCP the buffer would still exists ?

Comment: Yes.  But you may see different behavior with TCP since if your pier closes / crashes the OS will send a FIN or RST packet indicating that the connection is closed and after you consume the remaining data in the buffer you will get a 0 length read or read error .